# What is the need of 'join' in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

We can join 2 table using select statement, than what is the use for 'join' statement in joining of 2 table in mysql.. Is there any difference in using the both???

Answer (score 1):

In theory， yes； in practice， no. The SQL-92 Standard says that the infixed join notation is executed in left-to-right order in the FROM clause. But the optimizer is free to re-arrange the query as long as the results are the same.

This does not make a difference with INNER JOINs， but it is vital with OUTER JOINs.

There is a good story about this proposal. We needed the OUTER JOIN syntax； the proprietary methods in Oracle， SQL Server， Sybase，Informix， etc. were all screwed up. But after we had defined the OUTER JOIN， it was easy to extend the paper to INNER JOIN， UNION JOIN，NATURAL JOIN， etc. （most of which nobody implements）。

The rationale after the fact was that a product could have an option to force an order of execution with the infixed notation. Since SQL products now have some kind of optimizer， it is not really useful.

The real difference is in the mindset of programmers. Those that write with infixed notation thing in terms of a linear sequence of joins， as if they were limited to simple binary Theta operators. The programmers that use the older notation will use BETWEEN， IN （） and other predicates that work with multiple terms.

http://htc-hd2-android.blogspot.com/2011/03/difference-between-explicit-join-and.html

Answer (score 0):

A JOIN Statement is cleaner and more readable, it also alows for Flexibility later on if you need to make changes to the code, and a JOIN can be replaced with an INNER JOIN , OUTER JOIN, LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN depending on the type of Data you are wanting to get back.

It has always been told of me never to join 2 Table by a WHERE Clause.